# AJAX xmlHttp request GET undefined Index XML read file

Tags: php, xml, ajax

I am getting an undefined index error message on server side when i am trying to send a value selected from a dropdown box on client side (javascript/AJAX) to server side (php). I have a feeling that the GET on the client side is not sending the url correctly or if it is it is sending the value as null.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this issue. 
The code on the client is:

```
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
  $.getJSON("process.php", function(fileName) 
{           
    for(var i in fileName)
    {
        fileName[i] = fileName[i].split("../Test/").join("")
        fileName[i] = fileName[i].split(".xml").join("")
        document.dropDown.file[i]= new Option(fileName[i],"../Test/"+fileName[i]+".xml", false)
    }       
});

});

var xmlhttp;
function getFile(str){
alert("xmlprocess.php?filename="+str);
if (str=="")
{
   document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
   return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange= response(file);
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML= xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","xmlprocess.php?filename="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name = "dropDown">
<Select name = "file" onclick = "getFile(str1)" onchange = "str1 =    this.options[this.selectedIndex].value"></Select>
</form>

<div id="txtHint"></div>
</html>
```

and the code on the server side is :

```
<?php   
 ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

$br = "<br>";
$filename = $_GET["filename"];
echo $filename;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys ive found the answer

i had to change the onreadystatechange to be equal to a function on client side as shown below

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange= function(){
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
   {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML= xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
};
```